# How to sync a very large postgres database table to a web software using REST API Call?

Tags: java, postgresql, data-migration

Here are a few things you should know:

1. I have a postgres database that has a table 'account' which has about a million records.
2. I have a Vbout account where I need to sync the records from the 'account' table as contacts using the Vbout Rest API (https://developers.vbout.com/docs/1_0/#emailmarketing_addcontact).
3. I have created a python script to generate random data and populate rows into the postgres table to test.

I have written a Java Program to do this sync:

1. My java program first counts the number of records in the database and then divides the records into ranges (Say there are 100 records and I want to run 5 threads, the ranges are 1-20, 21-40, 41-60, 61-80, 81-100) and processes every range using a separate thread to make the process faster.
2. Each thread fetches a record and creates an object for the record and pushes the record in a Queue that i have implemented using an Arraylist.
3. I have 100 Threads for posting data into Vbout. These threads takes an object from the queue and makes an rest api call to vbout to create a contact there.

Here is the problem that I am facing:

1. The program is working fine for 10000 records but not for a million records.
2. When I populate the table with a million records, the PgAdmin as Well as my program crashes.
3. With a million records, my program show an connection error and PgAdmin shows a connection lost error.

Please help me. I am unable to solve this.

```
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


//DB Controller Class used to get Database Connection
//Have made it generic for future use
class DBController {

    private static final String dbName = "dbname";
    private static final String username = "postgres";
    private static final String password = "password";
    private static final String host = "localhost";


    public static Connection getDBConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://" + host + "/" + dbName,
                            username, password);


            return connection;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Connection To Database failed due to following reasons:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}


/*
 * Range Objects are used to divide all the records of the table
 * into parts. Then all the parts are processed by different threads to make the sync faster.
 * */
class Range {
    int from;
    int to;
}

//Vbout Contact Objects store the property for posting into the Vbout API
class VboutContact {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String email;
    String phone;
}


//This is the main class and this should be run only once (THE FIRST TIME) to do an initial sync
public class FirstSync {

   static int count=0;
    static int testCount=0;

    private static final String listId = "######";
    private static final String vboutApiKey = "#######";

    //Default Vbout Threads
    private static final int vboutThreads = 500;

    //Default Database Threads (eg. 5 Threads = 5 Range Objects)
    private static final int dbThreads = 100;

    private static int countRecords = 0;


    //We maintain a queue of contacts that every thread add the records into
    private static volatile ArrayList<VboutContact> contactQueue = new ArrayList<VboutContact>();


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");


        System.out.println("Connected to database!");


        countRecords = countRecords();
        doSync();


        Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doPostVbout();
            }
        };

        //Runs vboutThreads number of threads for posting data into vbout default (3)
        for (int i = 0; i < vboutThreads; i++) {
            new Thread(r1).start();
        }

    }

    public static void doPostVbout() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (contactQueue.size() > 0) {
                    VboutContact vboutContact = null;
                    synchronized (contactQueue) {
                        vboutContact = contactQueue.remove(0);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Processing Vbout Contact : " + vboutContact.email+" - Name : "+vboutContact.firstName+" "+vboutContact.lastName+" Phone : "+vboutContact.phone);
                    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://api.vbout.com/1/emailmarketing/addcontact.json?key=" + vboutApiKey);
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", vboutContact.email));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", "Active"));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("listid", listId));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fields[161784]", vboutContact.firstName));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fields[161785]", vboutContact.lastName));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fields[161787]", vboutContact.phone));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("\n\n\nProgress : "+count+" / "+countRecords);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            System.out.println("Total Count Records: "+countRecords+" - Total Fetched Records"+testCount);
        }
    }

    public static boolean doSync() {
        boolean syncResultBool = false;
        try {

            //Counts Total Reords in the database
            int count = countRecords;

            //Breaks the total number of records into ranges
            ArrayList<Range> ranges = getRanges(count);

            //Runs Thread of each range
            for (int i = 0; i < ranges.size(); i++) {
                Range thisRange = ranges.get(i);
                Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        doSyncThread(thisRange);
                    }
                };
                Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
                t1.start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Sync Crashed Due To Following Issues");
        }
        return syncResultBool;
    }


    public static void doSyncThread(Range range) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Sync Running for " + range.from + " : " + range.to);
            Connection connection=DBController.getDBConnection();
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id,firstname,lastname,phone,personemail FROM public.account LIMIT ? OFFSET ?");
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, (range.to - range.from)+1);
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nLIMIT "+(range.to - range.from+1)+"OFFSET "+(range.from-1)+"\n\n\n");
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, range.from-1);

            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {

                VboutContact vboutContact = new VboutContact();
                vboutContact.firstName = rs.getString(2);
                vboutContact.lastName = rs.getString(3);
                //vboutContact.phone = rs.getString(4);
                vboutContact.phone = "9999999999";
                vboutContact.email = rs.getString(5).toLowerCase()+"@example.com";

                System.out.println("Adding Record to Queue : " + vboutContact.email);
                //Adds records to queue
                synchronized (contactQueue) {
                    contactQueue.add(vboutContact);
                    testCount++;
                }
            }
            rs.close();
            preparedStatement.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Sync Crashed Due To Following Issues");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static int countRecords() {
        int count = 0;
        try {

            Connection connection=DBController.getDBConnection();
            // make sure autocommit is off
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            st.setFetchSize(100);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select count(id) from account;");
            while (rs.next()) {
                count = rs.getInt(1);
                System.out.print("a row was returned.");
            }
            rs.close();
            st.close();
            connection.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Sync Crashed Due To Following Issues");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Total Records : " + count);
        countRecords=count;
        return count;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Range> getRanges(int count) {
        ArrayList<Range> arrayList = new ArrayList<Range>();
        int threads = dbThreads;
        int parts = count / threads;
        float partf = ((float) count / (float) threads) - (float) parts;
        int temp = Math.round(partf * threads);
        int d = parts;
        int t = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i <= threads + 1; i++) {
            Range range = new Range();
            range.from = t + 1;
            t = (i - 1) * d;
            range.to = t;
            range.to = (i == threads + 1) ? t + temp : t;
            arrayList.add(range);
        }
        return arrayList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A million records is not even "large" for PostgreSQL, much less "very large".  Using 100 threads to read a million records from the database is the problem, not the solution.  What lead you to believe that this would be a useful thing to do?  Perhaps you can helpfully use threads for vbout (I wouldn't know), but that doesn't mean you also need to use them for PostgreSQL.

You say PgAdmin crashed, but you haven't described any usage of PgAdmin.  What were you doing with it?  What was the exact error message?

You say your java program crashed.  What was the exact error message issued by PostgreSQL?

A good step to debugging your code is to *read your error messages*.  If you need help interpreting them, then you need to *show us your error messages*.